# FITCSVM not working the same as SVMTRAIN

Tags: matlab, svm

I have previously implemented a SVM classifier, using the Matlab function `svmtrain`, and classified a set of test data, using `svmclassify`. I used the following code to train the classifier:

```
SVMStruct = svmtrain(features, labels, 'options', options, 'boxconstraint', 10, 'kernel_function', 'rbf', 'rbf_sigma', 27, 'showplot', 'false')
```

I have set the `options` parameter as below:

```
options = statset('MaxIter', Inf)
```

Since Matlab is stopping its support for `svmtrain`, I tried to move to `fitcsvm`, as it has advised. I used the following code:

```
SVMModel = fitcsvm(features, labels, 'IterationLimit', Inf,'boxconstraint', 10, 'KernelFunction', 'rbf', 'KernelScale', 27)
```

The problem with the latter is that it converges so fast, with the message `Exiting Active Set upon convergence due to DeltaGradient.`, and when I use the `predict` function in order to classify a set of test data, it does not lead to same good results which I used to get from `svmtrain` and `svmclassify`.
What may have caused the problem? Am I using the `fitcsvm` function correctly?